# Loop through two csv files in python

Tags: python, loops, csv, indexing

I am trying to loop through two csv files and want to compare the strings between next column value and previous one. Program is working with one csv files but with two csv files its giving error: File "Gaze_calculaton.py", line 88, in 
                   if row[3] == "Gaze at robot":
                   IndexError: list index out of range

It is giving error in the end of first file. I tried few things, but it did not work.  Please help, as I am new to csvloop handling.

```
import csv
import os,sys
import glob

dirListing = glob.glob('/home/shruti/Desktop/Final eaf files/Teacher Gaze/*.csv')
print dirListing
for fname in dirListing:
    `enter code here`last =None
last1 =None

with open(fname,'rb') as f:
    for row in list(csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')):
       #print row[3]

       i      += 1
       print i 
       print fname
       if last == "Gaze at robot" and row[3]== "Gaze at learner" :
           b += 1
           print "b",b 
           print last
           print row[3]
       if last1 == "Gaze at learner" and row[3]== "Gaze at robot" :
           c += 1
           print "c",c 
           print last1
           print row[3]     
       if row[3] == "Gaze at robot":
           last = row[3]
       if row[3] == "Gaze at learner":
           last1 = row[3]

    print b,c
    f.close()
```

Comment: You have a line in one of your files that has three or fewer comma-separated values on.  Since you're trying to look at the fourth value on the line (`row[3]`), the index `3` is out-of-range.

Comment: Your indenting looks off. is the `with open...` section supposed to be nested in the `for fname in dirListing` loop body?

Comment: @ calpratt: Sorry, It was a mistake while pasting the code.

Comment: @ Larry: Thanks! I removed headers from both the files, and it is working now.